# ASPNET Application não envia emails

Tags: c#, webforms, aplicação-web, email

Tenho uma aplicação que  possui uma tela com envio de emails,
essa aplicação funciona 100% em um servidor virtual (MANWEB10), inclusive o envio de emails. AO exportar para esse novo servidor (MANWEB01) o envio de emails simplesmente não funciona mais, com isso pode-se destacar que o erro não é no código e sim na configuração do servidor.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda de onde exatamente eu faço isso?
O novo servidor é Windows 2008 R2 Standard e usa o IIS 7

Comment: Você trocou a configuração de SMTP que está no seu Web.Conf, ou é a mesma?

Comment: é a mesma.. a aplicação toda é a mesma coisa, não mudei nenhuma linha de código

Comment: Muito estranhu isso, Qual a configuração do seu servidor antigo?

Comment: era um Windows Server 2003, a configuração completa fica difícil de copiar

Comment: Entendi @Pedro MArtine. Você conseguiu pegar algum erro no C#?

Comment: A porta 587 está aberta no firewall? Tem a descrição do erro?

Comment: Atualize sua pegunta com a configuração do e-mail e como está utilizando.

Answer (score 1):

Se voce nao mudou nada no código, o problema pode estar nas configurações de SMTP do próprio servidor.

Veja neste passo a passo da Microsoft se ficou alguma configuração sem fazer no seu servidor novo.

[Configure SMTP E-mail (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Então...

1 - Verifique seu servidor de SMTP;

2 - verifique qual porta está saindo, usuário e senha;

Tente fazer um teste via telnet, use este site como exemplo.

http://www.andersonpatricio.org/testando-envio-de-e-mail-via-telnet-3/